# Connecting to a Windows Remote Desktop from Ubuntu with RD Gateway?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, remote-access, lubuntu

I would like to connect to a remote Windows desktop session from my Lubuntu desktop. The IT department don't know or support linux, so the only help they gave was that I should like for a linux-client that supported RD Gateway.

I found [this excellent guide for FreeRDP](http://ifconfig.dk/freerdp/). It got me some of the way.

with FreeRdp, I seem to be able to connect to the .rdp-file is supplied to me. However, I get this error:

```
Protocol security negotation failure
freerdp connect error exit status 1
```

[My rep isn't high enough to post pictures so here is the link to a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11iOv.png)

I think it might be because I don't now the Gateway Domain (see picture) that freeRDP is asking for when using the .rdp-file. The IT department suggested dstfse, but that isn't working.

Does anyone know how to solve this? This is the only thing keeping me from using Linux at work and that would be sooo much more relaxed and productive!

Emil

Comment: Just a guess, but it's possible the RDP client you're using doesn't support connections to an RDP Gateway.

Comment: No, this client explicitly does. That's why I chose it :)